# FBSession fails to open for the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I've got a problem when i try to open facebook session for the first time - i get facebook error 5 (not authorised). In fact, i do not get this popup where user is asked for permissions. However if i stop the app and run it again, everything works fine (i see the popup and there is no fb error 5). I can't find any reason for such behavior.

```
if ([FBSession.activeSession isOpen]) {
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info", @"email"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {NSLog(@"error"); return;}
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:nil];
        }];
}

- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState)state error:(NSError *)error {
switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen: {
        [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"test");
        }
        break;
    }
// do something else
}
```

Error 5:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x165b1b10 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 190;
        "error_subcode" = 458;
        message = "Error validating access token: The user has not authorized application 1111111111.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x1664ad70, state: FBSessionStateClosed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 111111111, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x16576320>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code along with ur code. Help it will resolve ur problem.

```
-(void)openSession
{
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"friends_birthday",
                        nil];
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
{
  //[self.sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
  }];
}
```

Go to `AppDelegate.m` File and Add the given below Code-

```
-(void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (state){
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        if (!error)
        {
        // We have a valid session
        NSLog(@"User session found");
        }

        break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        NSLog(@"sesion close");

        break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        NSLog(@"sesssion failed");

        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
     default:
        break;
}

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 postNotificationName:UIDocumentStateChangedNotification
 object:session];

if (error) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error"
                              message:error.localizedDescription
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}


-(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI
{

NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                        @"user_location",
                        @"user_birthday",
                        @"user_likes",
                        @"friends_birthday",
                        nil];

return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error)
                                                                    {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];}];
}
```

Comment: I can't see any difference between your code and my code in logic. You're opening session, same as me, then you handle sessionStateChanged:state:error same as me ;)

Comment: k. did u added the coded in AppDelegate.m. for state get changed

Comment: No, I have this code in custom class. This shouldn't matter where you have this method.

Comment: @Vive exactly... does ur code contains -(BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI

Comment: Well your code also do not contain this method. Both our codes contains method `openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:`. Do you suggest the code should contain this method also?

Comment: @Vive now check the updated answer...i think it will work now. i also faced same issue but i got it resolved by doing this, what i have suggested u..

Comment: I still don't understand your solution. The code in appDelegate (method openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:) will never be called. Also it does exactly same thing like openSession: method (with different permissions, but this doesn't matter.

Comment: @Vive return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url] in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application....

Comment: No, as far this solution does not resolve my issue. However thanks for trying^^.

Comment: Ok I've checked this solution and the only thing it does is asking twice for these permissions. In my code if such error is returned I'm just calling my method again. Still your code provided me a clue so I'm going to accept it. For the next time I'm going to use Social.framework instead of this buggy SDK.